# Best table structure for users with different roles

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

We are working on a website which will feature about 5 different user roles, each with different properties. In the current version of the database schema we have a single *users* table which holds all the users, and all of their properties.

The problem is that the properties that we need differ per user role. All users have the same basis properties, like a name, e-mail address and password. But on top of that the properties differ per role. Some have social media links, others have invoice addresses, etc. In total there may be up to 60 columns (properties), of which only a portion are used by each user role.

In total we may have about 250,000 users in the table, of which the biggest portion (about 220,000) will be of a single user role (and use about 20 of the 60 columns). The other 30,000 users are divided over four other rules and use a sub-set of the other 40 columns.

What is the best database structure for this, both from a DB as a development perspective? My idea is to have a base *users* table, and then extend on that with tables like *users*_ *moderators*, but this may lead to a lot of JOIN'ed queries. A way to prevent this is by using VIEWs, but I've read some (out-dated?) articles that VIEWs may hurt performance, like: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/.

Does the 'perfect' structure even exist? Any suggestion, or isn't this really a problem at all and should we just put all users in a single big tables?

Answer (score 2):

There are two different ways to go about this.  One is called "Single Table Inheritance".  This is basically the design you ask for comments on.  It's pretty fast because there are no joins.  However NULLs can affect throughput to a small degree, because fat rows take a little longer to bring into memory than thinner rows.

An alternative design is called "Class Table Inheritance".  In this design, there is one table for the super class and one table for each subclass.  Non key attributes go into the table where they pertain.  Often, a design called "Shared Primary Key" can be used with this design.  In shared primary key,  the key ids of the subclass tables are copies of the id from the corresponding row in the superclass table.

It's a little work at insert time,  but it pays for itself when you  go to join data.

You should look up all three of these in SO (they have their own tags) or out on the web.  You'll get more details on the design, and an indication of how well each design fits your case.

Answer (score 1):

'Perfect' structure for such cases, in my opinion, is party-role-relationship model. Search for Len Silverston's books about data models. It looks quite complicated at the beginning, but it gives great flexibility...

The biggest question is practicability of adopting perfect solution. Nobody except you can answer that. Refactoring is never an easy and fast task, so say if your project lifetime is 1 year, spending 9 month paying out 'technical debts' sounds more like wasting of time/efforts/etc.

As for performance of joins, having proper indexes usually solves potential issues. If not, you can always implement materialized view ; even though mysql doesn't have such option out of the box, you can design it yourself and refresh it in different ways(for instance, using triggers or launch refresh procedure periodically/on demand).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I understand your suggestion to apply the party-role-relationship correctly, we should put only the minimum amount of columns in the users, and then extend that table in other tables (the party relationship)?

Comment: @vvanscherpenseel : yeah, ideally user table has just very few columns, information related to user as a member of particular role is stored in other table[s]. Also, some data really makes sense only within certain relationship, so it can be a bit tricky to identify the right storage - user_role or relationship...

Comment: I understand. It's a good option that I'll definitely consider.

Answer (score 1):

`table user
table roles
table permissions
table userRole
table userPermission
table RolesPermissions`

Each role have is permissions in role permissions table
Each user can have a permission whitout the role (extention...)

So in PHP you just have to merge arrays of user permissions in user roles and extended permissions...
And in your "acl" class you check if your user have the permission to view or process a webpage or a system process...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my question is not about the ACL part, but about the storage of role-dependent properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to worry about speed here so much.
Because it will be one time thing only. i.e. on user login store acl in session and get it next time from there.

JOINs are not so bad. If you have your indexes and foreign keys in right places with InnoDB engine it will be really fast.

I would use one table for users and role_id. Second table with roles. Third table for resources, and one to link it all together + enabled flag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you suggest keeping all users in a single table, regardless of the fact that for 220,000 users 40 columns will be empty?

Comment: Lets agree that 220,000 rows are nothing. I agree that 40 columns is bad engineering. You could use EAV model to store related user data. I don't really like every user group data to table idea.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. EAV is a possibility here, although it might be a bit too far on the other side of the scale. It could be overkill for 60 properties, but I'll definitely consider it as an option.